# Group/combine rows and save the data which is'nt null

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to write a SQL command which groups rows from the following table.

```
+------------+---------+----------+
|    DATE    |   RED   |   BLUE   |
+------------+---------+----------+
| 2018-01-01 |   YES   |   null   |
| 2018-06-11 |   YES   |   null   |
| 2018-06-11 |   null  |   YES    |
+------------+---------+----------+
```

The result I'm trying to achieve is the following:

```
+------------+---------+----------+
|    DATE    |   RED   |   BLUE   |
+------------+---------+----------+
| 2018-01-01 |   YES   |   null   |
| 2018-06-11 |   YES   |   YES    |
+------------+---------+----------+
```

BUT, I can't get the command to combine/group the two rows with the same date and overwrite existing NULL values during grouping.

Any ideas? I'm using MySQL by the way.

Comment: Can we see your attempt?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `group by` already said in comments

```
     select  DATE,max(RED) as  RED,max(BLUE) as BLUE  from t1
     group by DATE
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e7gxBPx5pyAPELqh516Hpn/1

```
DATE        RED BLUE
2018-01-01  YES null
2018-06-11  YES YES
```

Comment: Huge thanks! I can't believe that I missed the MAX() command. :$

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement, I guess you can try the below:

```
  select A.Xdate,max(Red) as C2 ,max(Blue) as C3  from test A  
  group by A.XDate;
```